# Get object with index of object in list yii php

Tags: php, yii

This is code query data from database :

```
public function getAllUser(){
    $connect = Yii::app()->db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $statement = $connect->CreateCommand($query);
    $result = $statement->query();
    return $result;
}
```

After that I use Controller to get data & send to View :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $consultas = new ConsultasDB();
    $listUser = $consultas->getAllUser();

    $this->render('index',  array
             ("listUser" => $listUser));
}
```

In View I know show all information from database by loop listUser

```
foreach ($listUser->readAll() as $user)
{
    echo 'Username : '.$user["username"].'<br>';
    echo 'Password : '.$user["password"].'<br>';
}
```

but I don't know how to get a object with an index. Ex: User[1]...
Thanks!

Comment: @haunhqn `getAllUser()` will return you an `array`

Comment: thanks everyone..I did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your view, before the `foreach` loop

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($listUser->readAll());
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps you out.!